# How to add conditions in Parameters section in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

So what I am trying to do is, I defined a Parameter called EnvType with allowed values test or production.

What should happen is when the user selects one of these environments test or production, lets say test
then he should be able to select another parameter called InstanceType in which allowed values would be all the 't' type instances in the drop-down list while creating the stack.

If the user selects production as the EnvType then the allowed values under the same parameter called InstanceType must be all instances types except 't' type for eg ('m' type).

And the same must apply for rds as well. Let's say user chooses EnvType as test then allowed values under parameter called DBInstanceType must be 'db.t' type instances otherwise 'db.r' type instances.

**Parameters**

```
Parameters:
  
  EnvType: 
    Default: test
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: 
      - production
      - test
  
  InstanceType:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: !FindInMap 
      - InstanceTypeMap
      - !Ref EnvType
      - instanceType
      
  DBInstanceType:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: !FindInMap 
      - InstanceTypeMap
      - !Ref EnvType
      - dbinstanceType
```

**Mapping**

```
    InstanceTypeMap:
      production:
        instanceType: [m1.small, m1.medium, m1.large, m1.xlarge, m2.xlarge, m2.2xlarge, m2.4xlarge]
        dbinstancetype: [db.r5.large, db.r5.xlarge]
      test:
        instanceType: [t1.micro, t2.nano, t2.micro, t2.small, t2.medium, t2.large]
        dbinstancetype: [db.t2.small, db.t2.medium, db.t3.small]
```

**Resources**

```
Resources:
  WebServer:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
   

  DBInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: !FindInMap 
        - MyEnvironmentMap
        - !Ref EnvType
        - dbinstanceType
```

Well i know the template is not valid, and is prone to errors in allowed values in InstanceType and DBInstanceType parameters but i am seeking an alternative of doing this.

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, such functionality is **not possible** in CloudFormation (CFN). Sadly, there is no alternative in CFN for that. You would have to develop a custom solution for deployment of such templates.

Comment: Could you please guide me as to how to develop custom solution for my use-case ?

Comment: @SaiPranav Sadly I can't. Its use-case specific and there is no one-solution that would fit all possible scenarios.

Comment: Ok, no worries, anyways thanks for your response !!